# Device Token not received

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

iPhone device is not receiving device token from my application. The

```
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
```

method is not getting called though I have the following code in the

```
didFinishLaunch
```

method.

In `didFinishLaunch` Method:

```
let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

Note:

1. `notificationSettings` method is getting called. but not `didRegister` or `didFail` methods called for Remote Notifications.
2. I am using a iPhone 6s with iOS 9.

What need to be checked to get the device token?

Answer (score 1):

try this in didFinishLaunch

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    } else {         
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    // ios 10
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
            // actions based on whether notifications were authorized or not
        }

        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    // iOS 9 support
    else if #available(iOS 9, *) {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    else
    {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `UNUserNotificationCenter` but it only work if your device with iOS 10 or 10+.

For iOS 9 you need below code for register push notification

```
UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: nil))
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

You can add condition based on iOS version like **@Kamalesh** answer.